# generate a master key as short as possible

Tags: algorithm, numbers

this is an interview question:

Say if we have a lock, the lock has a 4-digits password, the password only contains numbers 0-9. For example, the password is 1234.

In order to open the lock, we can enter a string of numbers. This string can be very long and if the string contains the password, we say this string is a valid key to open the lock.

For example, if the lock has a password of 1234, we enter 176461234, 176461234 is a valid key because the last four digits is 1234 and 176461234 is also a valid key for 1764, 7646, .... 000881234 is also valid for 1234, but 78123 is not.

How to generate a string master key as short as possible to solve all passwords from 0000 to 9999?

Comment: Are you in the interview... now?

Comment: Interview w/ internet access? :-) not fair

Comment: The best you can do is with 4 digits for the first combination, and then 1 digit for every additional combination. In other words, a string of 10003 digits (I'm not sure if this is feasible though).

Comment: No, my friend told me about this question, I think it is very interesting.

Comment: @barakmanos This will not be the shortest key and you can break the logic even for 2 or 3 digits.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: How can you cover all 10000 possible combinations in less than 10003 digits then? (theoretically if you don't have an exact solution).

Comment: @barakmanos Let's consider two digits you can write `01234567890246813579147036925826048...` I did not finish it because writting the solution by hand is a bit slow but here I cover 33 pairs in 34 digits. My estimate is that I will need about 102 to cover all possible pairs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/166094/shortest-common-superstring-find-shortest-string-that-contains-all-given-strin

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: I meant the best OP could hope for (and I explicitly stated that it may not be possible).

Comment: @barakmanos aahhh I see

Comment: a code can give you the answer,
make a loop that goes from 0000 to 9999 and add the value to an array iff it isn't a substring of that array

Comment: @Fanckush: That already fails for n=2: (1) Check whether 0000 is a substring of what we have so far; it's not, so append it.  (2) Check whether 0001 is a substring of what we have so far; it's not, so append it, giving 00000001, which is 8 digits when the shortest representation is 00001 at 5 digits.

Comment: @j_random_hacker you have a point
how about: we start from 000010002... form 1-9 with 3 zeros between, then we skip 0010 so: ...0009000110012001300... having three zeros around a number is useful 0001 or 0010 or 0100 or 1000
so if when it was one digit we had 3 zeros, 2 digits 2 zeros and so on
the higher we go the more we skip, but i still can't find an algorithm :/

Comment: Why was this question blocked? The problem is nice and has a nice and easy to proof answer(yes, the minimal string will have 10003 digits) which I can't add...

Comment: @user1990169 This is not a duplicate. This is a special case (you are creating all of the possible words).

Comment: @Silnik hi Silnik, could you please post your proof somewhere I can see, so I think I can edit my post and share your answer.

Comment: @Woaibanzhuan here is how I see the answer (it's too long to be a comment): http://pastebin.com/xRQC5EhU

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. Completely forgot about the question.